# Unknown version of Tomcat was specified 8.0.24 / Eclipse 4.4.2 (Luna)

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

A couple of months ago, I downloaded and unzipped the tomcat 8.0.24 which is running flawlessly. I did some tests creating servlets in notepad, compiled with javac.exe and placed in webapps. It worked.

My version of Eclipse is 4.4.2 known as Luna.

My version of JRE is 1.8.0_65 (x64)

When I want to set my Server in Eclipse, I see this warning and I don't know what to do.

**Eclipse > Windows > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environments > Add**
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Tomcat Installation directory field is meant to be pointed at your Tomcat base directory.

So in your case just fill it with **D:\ApacheTomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.24** (without **bin** directory)

Answer (score 5):

In Ubuntu, point to the shared location; not the app location. Point to:
/usr/share/tomcat8
and fix what they did not test:

```
 cd /var/lib/tomcat8
 ln -s conf /usr/share/tomcat8/conf
```

Comment: Of course, then its all messed up as conf folder is in app location (/usr/lib/tomcat8) and not the "installation directory (/usr/share/tomcat8). It gets worse; but can probably link it to fake it out. Yep, seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

In Fedora, Just select this directory

/usr/share/tomcat

Answer (score 1):

This required path is where you untarred the file when downloaded. Generally, the path in Ubuntu systems is:

```
/usr/share/tomcat7
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried different locations, assign all permissions, but none of them works. so I moved tomcat folder to desktop and it works for me... mine is tomcat 8.5 and oxygen eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Tomcat version 7**
The problem is the variable JAVA_HOME, everything works for **TOMCAT version 7** but not for version 8 and 9 which always returns me "Unknown version of Tomcat was specified"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Look at the accepted answer. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Select same jdk which is use for tomcat at time of installation