# Eclipse not recognizing Apache Tomcat on Debian/Linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, apache, tomcat

I am trying to get an eclipse project to recognize the apache/tomcat(v8.0..) that I have installed, but I am having trouble. The installation is from `sudo apt-get install tomcat8`, which after a lot of errors I have finally managed to solve. Now I am getting the following after I hook up the tomcat install at `/usr/share/tomcat8` to a new project in eclipse.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The container 'Apache Tomcat v8.0 [Apache Tomcat v8.0]' references non existing library '/usr/share/tomcat8/lib/commons-dbcp.jar'   helloworld2     Build path  Build Path Problem
```

I'm not sure what the problem could be. There should be no unreferenced libraries as I have installed everything from sudo. I DID have to use this `ln -s conf /usr/share/tomcat8/conf` to get Eclipse to hook up  the library in the first place (as suggested here: [Unknown version of Tomcat was specified 8.0.24 / Eclipse 4.4.2 (Luna)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35306335/unknown-version-of-tomcat-was-specified-8-0-24-eclipse-4-4-2-luna)). So perhaps that broke it. The road to hello world continues.....

EDIT:

I tried the following:

```
patientplatypus@next /usr/share/tomcat8/lib $ sudo chmod u+x commons-dbcp.jar
chmod: cannot operate on dangling symlink 'commons-dbcp.jar'
```

So this appears to be another tomcat8 issue. On installation tomcat8 somehow makes a directory with dangling symlinks to important files. Why it does this or what the fix is, I  do not know.

Comment: Which version of tomcat are you using, latest tomcat8 does not even have commons-dbcp. In fact you should be using tomcat-jdbc pool instead of commons-dbcp.

Comment: that is incorrect. to test your theory I typed the following commands: sudo apt-get remove --purge tomcat*, sudo apt-get install tomcat8, cd /usr/share/tomcat8/lib, ls. Sure enough commons-dbcp.jar is there and is a dangling symlink. So.....that is not the solution.

Comment: I'm not saying that using tomcat-jdbc is the solution, I was only asking which version you are using, because the last 8.0 version is 8.0.44 and there is no common-dbcp.jar , there is a tomcat-dbcp.jar.
Maybe it is a dangling symlink because is not distributed anymore with tomcat8.

Answer (score 0):

I've not much linux experience, but I use tomcat and eclipse. Eclipse is a mix of java and platform specific binaries, but tomcat is java only (apart from tomcat native which is optional).

If your eclipse supports tomcat8 (I don't remember which version luna supports), you do not need (or even desire) a full server install of tomcat8, you just need to have tomcat package unzipped in any directory you choose, and just point to it.

Which is not the same as installing tomcat8 on your machine and then trying to make it work with eclipse.

My advice is:

1. Download [tomcat8](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi) and unpackage it on a folder.
2. Create a server runtime with eclipse pointing to that folder.
3. Develop.

Once you have a war to deploy, you can install tomcat8 on a machine and put your war there and use it.